# Proof of a common expression in Combinatorics.

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to know a mathematical proof of the following expression:

$${\sum\limits_{r=0}^n {n\choose{r}} {=} {2^n}}$$

Thank you!

Comment: Try to do it both using the binomial theorem and using a combinatorial argument.

Comment: Write the binomial formula of $(1+1)^n$.

Comment: Shit! That was an easy proof! I must be really dumb! -_-
Thank you for the answer! :)

Answer (score 5):

There is the [Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) that says
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k=(1+x)^n
$$
Plug in $x=1$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a combinatorial proof (just for fun):

The right hand side counts the number of subsets of an $n$-element set. The left hand side does the same, just in a different way. It counts the number of $r$-element subsets for each $r$, and then sums over $n$.

Since they both count the same number of things, just in different ways, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\text{For any pair of real (or complex, if you will) numbers}\;\;a,b\;:$$

$$\;\;\color{red}{(a+b)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom nia^ib^{n-i}}$$

Comment: In particular, $a=b=1$ :-)

Comment: @robjohn Yeah, well: you may as well write him the complete solution...:)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. :)